Make Rails UrlWriter generate https links when SSL is terminated at Load Balancer and internal traffic goes via http
I have following set-up in AWS:
ElasticLoadBalancer (SSL termination) -> EKS -> application_pod with Nginx and my app.
After load balancer there is http traffic and therefore I cannot force ssl in Rails application.
At load balancer we have http -> https redirect but it has to be turned off to target pentest finding. E.g. no way to keep this redirect.
We need to keep SSL termination at load balancer and have http traffic in EKS
When I generate a links using url_for(...), it automatically sets http://
Is there any way to configure UrlWriter to produce https:// links but don't force SSL at application level to keep whole application work over http?

Is this what you are looking for? Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'.
